# Keeping current date range in dygraphs when updating rollmean

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I really like the zoom function of dygraphs for R and tried to combine it with shiny for a simple plot app. I can load and plot data, but when I change the rollmean factor via a slider input or add an event using a mouse click when zoomed in on part of the plot, the plot is rerendered with the maximum date range.

As an attempt to solve this, I defined a new reactive function that stores the current view at a mouse click. Although this does almost what I want, there are still some issues

(i) It only works after a mouse click (in the plot), so zooming and than changing the rollmean still restores the original scale until one makes a mouse click

(ii) panning does not work (smoothly) anymore

(iii) when a new data file is loaded, it does not adjust the date range to fit the new file.

MWE:

```
# ui.R

library(dygraphs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Simple plot"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Data files must be 2 column format"),
      fileInput("inputfile",label = "Load File"),
      sliderInput("rollmean", label = "Running Average", 
                   value = 1, min = 1, max = 25, step = 1),
      textOutput("text1")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("dygraph")
    )
  )
))
```

and

```
# server.R

library(dygraphs)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  spectrum <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$inputfile
    read.table(inFile$datapath)
  })

  currentview <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$dygraph_click$x))
      {return(NULL)}
    else
    {
      input$dygraph_date_window
    }
  })

  cut <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$dygraph_click$x))
      return(NULL)
    cut <- input$dygraph_click$x
  })

  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    if (is.null(input$inputfile)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else{
      dygraph(spectrum(), main = input$inputfile$name) %>%
      dyOptions(drawXAxis = TRUE, drawYAxis = FALSE, drawGrid = FALSE,animatedZooms = FALSE) %>%
      dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = currentview(), fillColor = "") %>% 
      dyRoller(rollPeriod = input$rollmean, showRoller = FALSE) %>%
      dyEvent(cut())}
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", input$dygraph_click$x)
  })

})
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdy5vgnwlkz0sa3/test2.txt?dl=0) is a simple data file.

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] dygraphs_1.1.1.4 shiny_1.0.3     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7     lattice_0.20-34 zoo_1.8-0       digest_0.6.10  
 [5] mime_0.5        grid_3.3.3      R6_2.2.1        xtable_1.8-2   
 [9] jsonlite_1.4    magrittr_1.5    xts_0.9-7       tools_3.3.3    
[13] htmlwidgets_0.8 httpuv_1.3.3    yaml_2.1.13     htmltools_0.3.5
```

Comment: Seems to reject all of the data frames that I try. What should I be loading? "2 column format" means nothing to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added a data file that worked for me.

Comment: 1 - that file doesn't work, but I could see what you mean, so I just dummied up some data to make the program work. The first column is being read in as a factor. Could be you have changed some reading defaults on your system.

Comment: 2 - everything seems to work fine for me. I can zoom and pan no problem. Everything is also quite fast.

Comment: 3 - there is no date range in your example data - so there is none in my dummy data. So I cannot see your problem #3 either. I would suggest you create a few data files and test them more carefully.

Comment: You might want to include the output from your `sessionInfo()` so we can see if this is a version problem.

Comment: Peculiar that the data file does not work for you. I can zoom and pan as well, but when I am zoomed in and change the bar slider for the rollmean the plot zooms out again. After clicking in the graph so that an event line is plotted, the plot range does not change when changing the rollmean but the panning reacts strangely.

Comment: I take one of those statements back, it starts out fast, but then it gets slow after you play with it awhile. Interesting.

Comment: I used this:     `n <- 1000;  period <- 100;  df <- data.frame(idx=1:n,x=sin(pi*1:n/period)+0.4*rnorm(n))` for dummy data. But there are no dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using the `retainDateWindow` option of `dyRangeSelector` and a boolean parameter that is set to FALSE when new data is loaded. I also had to move the line containing the `dyRangeSelector` keyword to the end of the options block of `dygraphs` to get the desired behavior.

new server.R file:

```
# server.R

library(dygraphs)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  spectrum <- reactive({
    keepscale <<-FALSE
    inFile <- input$inputfile
    read.table(inFile$datapath)
  })

  cut <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$dygraph_click$x))
      return(NULL)
    cut <- input$dygraph_click$x
  })

  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    if (is.null(input$inputfile)){
      keepscale <<-FALSE
      return(NULL)
    }
    else{
      simpleplot<-dygraph(spectrum(), main = input$inputfile$name) %>%
      dyOptions(drawXAxis = TRUE, drawYAxis = FALSE, drawGrid = FALSE,animatedZooms = FALSE) %>%
      dyRoller(rollPeriod = input$rollmean, showRoller = FALSE) %>%
      dyEvent(cut()) %>%
      dyRangeSelector(retainDateWindow=keepscale, fillColor = "")}
      keepscale <<-TRUE
      return(simpleplot)
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", input$dygraph_click$x)
  })

})
```